# How do applications determine "fullscreen" size based upon open display?

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors

Say I have two monitors:

```
Left = 1280 x 768
Right = 1920 x 1200
```

I open a program on `Right` which in the control panel is set to my primary display. When I hit the "maximize" button, it expands to fill the `1920 x 1200` as expected. Now say I de-maximize it and drag it to `Left` and repeat. Well now it is only expanded to `1280 x 768` and all the internal elements scaled correctly as well; I presume the internals are on a relative metric of some type.

But how does an application *know* which display it is currently on?

Comment: What do you mean by "open display"? Did you mean to use the word "only" in the last sentence? What are you trying to accomplish with this information? Is there a related problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: "open" meaning the display (monitor) the application's frame/window is on. So if you had 2 monitors, program originally opened on the right and you moved it to the left monitor, how does it know to maximize to THAT monitors resolution (which could potentially be different than the one on the right)?

Comment: So are you trying to solve a problem, or just looking for knowledge? Is this a programming question?

Comment: @music2myear Knowledge, and maybe one day (not currently working that problem) apply it to a programming problem.

Comment: Windows provides the necessary information to the applications, in general. Most programs don't care about specific pixel counts and instead use pre-defined elements in whatever framework they were written in that handle the window and element sizing.

Comment: You enumerate the active displays then [get windows display capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4631379/436063). A DPI-aware framework will handle pretty much everything interesting except icon size selection.

Comment: Can you be specific about the level of detail you're looking for?  Obviously, applications are aware of their environment, a role of the OS.  Answers could range from trivial to books.

Comment: @fixer1234 I was just curious how an application would talk to the OS to say "which monitor am I being displayed on"? The link from Andrew pointed me to several combinations of WINAPI calls (I was already using `GetSystemMetrics` but wasn't sure how to get that from an applications current monitor).